# How do I create an html input field which will auto fill totp verification codes

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

My requirement is to have an input field which will allow iOS 15+ totp verification code auto fill.

I am using angular + cordova

I have already tried

```
autocomplete=‘one-time-code’
```

This didn’t really have any effect

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066417/setting-autofill-in-cordova-for-ios)

You also need to make sure that your message has [Origin-bound one-time codes](https://wicg.github.io/sms-one-time-codes/)

Comment: I am not looking for SMS auto fill. 

This is for the TOTP Authenticator built into iOS.